# JavaScript form validation for a form with a checkbox, radio button and select menu

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I cannot seem to figure out the form validation code completely.
I need validation for all options, including the radio buttons and the checkboxes, along with the select option menu.

I am supposed to validate whether the user has entered data in the input text box, has checked a radio button, has checked at least one checkbox, and has selected an option from the select items.

Use a submit button to invoke the validation script, so that the form is processed only when the form fields are valid.

If a field is invalid then display a message to the user.

In your form statement, use method="post" and an action that can be a mailto or a webpage(displaying that the form has been processed), but be sure to use input type="submit" for your submit button.

Alternatively you can leave out the form's action and method, but then you should use an input type="button", along with displaying any appropriate messages.
 
Make sure that if you display an error message because of a single field, you do not clear out the whole entire form .

```js
function Validate1() {
  var nam = document.forms["VacayForm"]["name"];
  var dom = document.forms["VacayForm"]["domestic"];
  var int = document.forms["VacayForm"]["international"];
  var sel = document.forms["VacayForm"]["select"];
  var agree = document.forms["VacayForm"]["agree"];

  //if (name.value == "")
  //{
  // window.alert("Please enter your name.");
  // name.focus();
  // return false;
  //}
  if (document.VacayForm.name.value == "") {
    alert("Please provide your name!");
    document.VacayForm.name.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (domestic.value == "")
  else(international.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please select domestic or international preference to proceed.");
    domestic.focus();
    international.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (select.selectedIndex < 1) {
    alert("Please select where you prefer to visit");
    select.focus();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 style="text-align: center">Vacation Vote Form</h1>
  <form name="VacayForm" action="mailto:you@domain.com" onsubmit="return Validate1()" method="post">
    <p>Name:<input type="text" name="name" size="25"></p><br>
    <p>Do You Prefer an international destination?</p>
    <p>Domestic<input type="radio" name="domint" value="domestic"></p>
    <p>International<input type="radio" name="domint" value="international"></ <br>
      <p>Where would you like to go?</p>
      <select type="text" name="continent" value="select" size="1">
        <option value="domestic">Domestic</option>
        <option value="europe">Europe</option>
        <option value="camerica">Central America</option>
        <option value="asia">Asia</option>
        <option value="aus">Australia</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <p>Check the box to act as your digital signature to cast your vote<input type="checkbox" value="agree" name="sig">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" onclick="if(!this.form.sig.checked){alert('You must agree to cast your vote by checking the box.');
    return false}">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: please check   if (domestic.value == "") { // code } not declared.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you are saying. please add some context

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Validate1() {
  var nam = document.forms["VacayForm"]["name"];
  var dom = document.forms["VacayForm"]["domestic"];
  var int = document.forms["VacayForm"]["international"];
  var sel = document.forms["VacayForm"]["select"];
  var agree = document.forms["VacayForm"]["agree"];

  //if (name.value == "")
  //{
  // window.alert("Please enter your name.");
  // name.focus();
  // return false;
  //}
  if (document.VacayForm.name.value == "") {
    alert("Please provide your name!");
    document.VacayForm.name.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (domestic.value == "")
  {
     window.alert("Please select domestic preference to proceed.");
     domestic.focus();
     return false;
  }
  else if(international.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please select international preference to proceed.");
    international.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (select.selectedIndex < 1) {
    alert("Please select where you prefer to visit");
    select.focus();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 style="text-align: center">Vacation Vote Form</h1>
  <form name="VacayForm" action="mailto:you@domain.com" onsubmit="return Validate1()" method="post">
    <p>Name:<input type="text" name="name" size="25"></p><br>
    <p>Do You Prefer an international destination?</p>
    <p>Domestic<input type="radio" name="domint" value="domestic"></p>
    <p>International<input type="radio" name="domint" value="international"></ <br>
      <p>Where would you like to go?</p>
      <select type="text" name="continent" value="select" size="1">
        <option value="domestic">Domestic</option>
        <option value="europe">Europe</option>
        <option value="camerica">Central America</option>
        <option value="asia">Asia</option>
        <option value="aus">Australia</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <p>Check the box to act as your digital signature to cast your vote<input type="checkbox" value="agree" name="sig">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" onclick="if(!this.form.sig.checked){alert('You must agree to cast your vote by checking the box.');
    return false}">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, but i appreciate the effort!!